# Server not running PHP script

Tags: php, session, header

I have a simple PHP script that is supposed to redirect to another document after running some code, like so:

```
    if...{
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['login_status'] = true;
        header('location: index.php');
    }
    else{...
```

The script works fine on one of the servers I have tried it on but not on the other. As it seems the other server doesn't go to the 'header' row but just stops running half way. All I am left with is a blank page with the title of the previous page. Why is that? Any ideas?

The PHP version on the server that runs the script is 5.1.6, the server that doesn't 4.3.9, not that I believe that has anything to do with it.

Comment: if you can turn on error reporting and "view source" in your browser. If there is any output previous to header() the script will stop.

Comment: did you check the response header? is it a `200 OK`? Or perhaps an internal server error has occured? Also, you should make sure that errors are configured to be displayed. Check the settings for `error_reporting` and `display_errors`...

Comment: Holy camoly! A six year old [PHP version](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-4.php#4.3.9)?!

Comment: @konsolenfreddy... I know right... And it's a university server running it! I politely asked them whether any updates are coming anytime soon and in the most rude tone they pretty much answered me that they don't need the advice of any hobby-programmers! (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your code with error reporting, so that you will get some clue about the error

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

See [PHP Error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Still not sure what caused the problem, but error reporting indeed did the trick. I got a error message that went something in the lines of: "headers already sent". I moved the php and the html part that was to render the form into the same php file, and voila, it worked on both servers...

Comment: Ok so there may be a blank space creating when it renders before the line header('location: index.php'); May be you can find it when verify all the above line in your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you started the session? Or your server might be just misconfigured.
Read the logs.

Comment: The session is started. The problem was related to headers being sent multiple times, which the other server seemingly din not approve of. Thanks for the reply, though!

Answer (score 1):

Check from php settings whether `session.auto_start` is enabled.

Also, it might be that older version of PHP doesn't know how to parse the `location: ...` string.
So change it to uppercase (so it conforms to HTTP specification):

```
header('Location: index.php')
```

Comment: As you from above the problem was seemingly related to headers, but not the standard used... Thanks for the reply, though!